# Mapping columns in xml to diffrent columns in dataset

Tags: xml, vb.net, ado.net, mapping, dataadapter

**Summary:**

- I have a folder full of `XML` documents created by an old strongly
  typed data set.
- I need the functionality of a tool that can access a data source,
  implement mappings and port the data into a data set. The problem is 
  that the data source is a collection of `XML` and not an actual `DBMS`.

**Explanation:**

What I can't manage is to map these old strongly typed columns, to new column names created by an `XSD` in my program.

With this data loaded correctly into my strongly typed Data set, I could then use the data-set's  writexml function to translate the old `XML` files into validated data.

I am familiar with the options involving `XLST`, but I'd rather avoid it if possible.

As far as I can tell, there is support for mappings, but only if the data resides in a Database Management System like `Microsoft SQL Server`. If it did I could use a data adapter and supply mappings.

Comment: Why can't you just load the data into a `DataSet`, create a second `DataSet` with the new schema, then write code to copy the data from the one to the other, then save the new, transformed, `DataSet` to XML?  I'm not sure what your question is.  Are you just hoping there's some built in feature of the `DataSet` that lets you do that transformation without writing the code to do it?

Comment: My hopes were that what you have described already existed. In hopes I could build a dictionary of conversions and supply them to the non-existent data-adapter I described in the OP. I could create an automated `XML` upgrading tool without having to build the definitions each time. The method you described is how I currently solve the problem.